# Add up total player points based on player ID

Tags: javascript, object, math

Take the following markup:

```
<div data-player-id="1" data-points="8">Player 1</div>
<div data-player-id="1" data-points="8">Player 1</div>
<div data-player-id="2" data-points="5">Player 2</div>
<div data-player-id="2" data-points="5">Player 2</div>
<div data-player-id="3" data-points="6">Player 3</div>
```

What I would like to do is combine the points for each `data-player-id`.

So my thought was to iterate over `data-player-id` and create an object for each player, like so:

```
const points = [];

document.querySelectorAll('[data-player-id]').forEach((element) => {
  const player = {
    id: element.getAttribute('data-player-id'),
    points: element.getAttribute('data-points'),
  }

  // Combine all players with the same "id"

  points.push(player);
});
```

The problem I'm having is merging all objects with the same `id`.

It doesn't necessarily have to be an object, if using an array is better, I'm happy to go down that route.

Comment: While looping, search `points` for an object with the same `player.id` as `element.getAttribute('data-player-id')`; if it exists, increment `player.points`, otherwise, create and add a new `player`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for which you can provide an initial value. Here I've used an object so that the player ids are the keys, and the property values are the points. I've also used destructuring on the element to grab the id and points values from the dataset instead of using `getAttribute`.

```js
const els = document.querySelectorAll('[data-player-id]');

const points = [...els].reduce((acc, element) => {

  // Destructure the id and points from the dataset of the element
  const { dataset: { playerId, points } } = element;

  // If the id doesn't exist in the object create it
  // and set it to zero
  acc[playerId] = acc[playerId] || 0;

  // Add the new points to the total for that id
  // making sure you convert the string to a number
  acc[playerId] += +points;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(points);
```

```html
<div data-player-id="1" data-points="8">Player 1</div>
<div data-player-id="1" data-points="8">Player 1</div>
<div data-player-id="2" data-points="5">Player 2</div>
<div data-player-id="2" data-points="5">Player 2</div>
<div data-player-id="3" data-points="6">Player 3</div>
```

Comment: Legend! Thank you so much. I really need to figure out when to use `reduce()`

Answer (score 1):

You could transform your `points` variable into an object instead of array and use the player ID as the key. Then, on your `querySelector` loop, check if the player ID key already exists in the `points` object, and in that case, sum the points. If it doesn't exist, set it to the points of the current element.

```js
const points = {};

document.querySelectorAll('[data-player-id]').forEach((element) => {
  const playerId = element.getAttribute('data-player-id');
  const playerPoints = parseInt(element.getAttribute('data-points'), 10);

  if (playerId in points) {
    points[playerId] += playerPoints;
  } else {
    points[playerId] = playerPoints;
  }
}
```

If you want to transform it later to the same data structure of your question, you can convert it afterwards:

```js
const players = {};
for (const playerId in points) {
  players.push({ id: playerId, points: points[playerId] });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. When I say "combine the total points", I don't mean concat the values, but instead add them all together

Comment: @Lodder I updated the answer. That was happening because playerPoints was a string, and we need to convert it to a number first using `parseInt`.

Comment: Just figured out that `parseInt()` was the only thing left. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

you'll have to look for the object with the player id in the points array, if found  add the points, push a new object otherwise :

```js
const pointsArr = [];

document.querySelectorAll('[data-player-id]').forEach((element) => {
  const player = {
    id: element.getAttribute('data-player-id'),
    points: +element.getAttribute('data-points')
  }

  const ndx = pointsArr.findIndex(e => e.id  === player.id);
  
  if(ndx > -1){
    pointsArr[ndx].points += +player.points;
  }
  else{
    pointsArr.push(player);
  }
});


console.log(pointsArr);
```

```html
<div data-player-id="1" data-points="8">Player 1</div>
<div data-player-id="1" data-points="8">Player 1</div>
<div data-player-id="2" data-points="5">Player 2</div>
<div data-player-id="2" data-points="5">Player 2</div>
<div data-player-id="3" data-points="6">Player 3</div>
```